# Определение типа хеша

Tags: php, md5, sha256

Недавно заметил сервис(http://finder.insidepro.team не реклама) там ты вводишь хеш, и оно само определяет тип и брутит. Кто знает, можно ли как-то определять тип на PHP?

Answer (score 3):

Что там определять-то. Длину строки измерил и всё, определил:

- MD5 — 128 бит (16 байт).
- SHA-1 — 160 бит (20 байт).
- SHA-256 — 256 бит (32 байта).
- SHA-512 — 512 бит (64 байта).

Но надо понимать, что на самом деле по хешу невозможно точно определить алгоритм. Существуют разные хеши с одинаковой длиной. Например MD3 и MD4 тоже имеют длину 128 бит. Просто они уже не используются. Или, например, нашумевший ГОСТ-овский Стрибог имеет длину 256 или 512 бит и его невозможно отличить от SHA-256/512.

Comment: А может это не SHA-256, а Стрибог? =)

Comment: @AlexeyTen Блин. Ну тогда никак :)

Comment: Тут везде алгоритм мд5.